# Sorting a list of lists C#

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have the following list of lists that I wish to sort by price:

```
List<object> StationList = new List<object>();
List<object> ListEntry = new List<object>();

ListEntry.Add(Name);  //string
ListEntry.Add(Area);  //string
ListEntry.Add(Price); //int

StationList.Add(ListEntry);
```

I have tried to sort it with:

```
List<object> SortedList = StationList.OrderBy(list => list[2]);
```

This gives me the error:

```
//Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'
```

How do I sort this list of lists?

Comment: Why are you even using `List<object>`? That's a pretty bad idea. Also, if anything, `StationList` should be a `List<List<object>>` instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, using a `List<object>` is a bad idea. Especially when used as a container for data that could (and should) be kept in a better structure.

It looks like your `StationList` should actually be a list of stations. So it would be a good idea to create a structure that describes a station. Maybe something like this:

```
public class Station
{
    public string Name { get;set; }
    public string Area { get;set; }
    public int Price { get;set; } /* although 'decimal' might be a better type */
}
```

Now the `StationList` can be defined and initialized as:

```
List<Station> StationList = new List<Station>();
/* although you could just call it 'Stations' */
```

Now create a new `Station` and fill it with data and add it to the `StationList`:

```
Station station = new Station();
station.Name = Name;
station.Area = Area;
station.Price = Price;

StationList.Add(station);
```

And if you want to order the list of stations by price, you can do it like:

```
List<Station> SortedList = StationList.OrderBy(entry => entry.Price).ToList();
```

Which (imho) is more readable than `list => list[2]`. Also, the whole thing is type safe, which means that you can be sure, that `StationList` will only contain instances of type `Station` (or types derived of `Station`) and you can access the `Name`, `Area` and `Price` properties of those instances directly, without having to cast them from type `Object` or having to remember which "property" is at which index in the list.

And if your going to work with the `Station` informations further, I'd guess you'll have a much easier time if you're using that class instead of `List<object>`.

Comment:  Just one thing: OrderBy does not produce a `List`

Comment: @Corak great answer, I was preparing to write a similar answer but there is no point. Upvote +1